# How to make "Scorzo" perspective with Blender Camera?

Tags: camera

I was wondering if it's possible (i guess it is), to make something like this:

[image]

Or like this...
[image]

So, how can i do this with the Blender camera?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The effect you are after is caused by the exaggerated foreshortening, or   relative size of the objects, caused an [extreme wide angle lens](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ultra_wide_angle_lens). It's wide field of view will make the elements that are close to the lens look much larger than elements that are slightly farther away.

To recreate that in blender, use a lens with a very **short focal length**( A smaller value in the lens will result in a wider angle for the field of view).

Then set the camera low, close to the ground and in close proximity to the character, and tilt up the camera to include the whole character within the frame

[image]

Here's a link to an interesting article on wide angle lenses:

https://www.cambridgeincolour.com/tutorials/wide-angle-lenses.htm